# Aggregating several models in a viewer with a base point

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, revit

I'm working on a custom 3D models viewer based on Forge Autodesk apis.
I'm having an issue with the display of several Revit models simultaneously : indeed, the models have the same base point, so they should align, however the models appear with an offset.

I've already tried several solutions, adding `globalOffset: { x: 0, y: 0, z: 0 }` in the viewer options, trying to get the Base Point to manually set the offset, but none of these solutions seemed to work.

How should I do to achieve this ?

Thanks in advance !

Enclosed : [screenshot of the viewer displaying the 2 models](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBxw3.jpg)

Comment: Can you send the model files to us if possible so we can look into the issue? Via a sharing service (e.g. weTransder/Dropbox) to forge.help@autodesk.com

Comment: Sure, will do as soon as possible !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer thanks to @BryanHuang ! I just needed to add `applyRefPoint: true` in the `modelOptions` to load the different models based on a reference point