# Multiple models (FBX, Revit) not coordinated correctly in Forge Viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I am trying to visualize different type of models in Forge Viewer, models might be FBX, Revit, NWD. In the screenshot below, Naviswork shows two models (RVT and FBX) and they are correctly positioned using the shared coordinate system.

[image]

Meanwhile, in Forge Viewer both models are separated:

[image]

I have translated both models to svf2 using Derivative API in POSTMAN, the following json body is sent to the /job endpoint:

```
{
  "input": {
    "urn": "dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWp8czpvcy5vYmpduh3Q6eWFzcjhsjyL0hVRUxWQ7UyMEdJUy5mYng="
  },
  "output": {
    "formats": [
        {
            "type": "svf2",
            "views": [
                "2d",
                "3d"
            ]
        }
   ]
  }
}
```

I have tried solutions suggested in different related [[issue1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56733831/aggregating-several-models-in-a-viewer-with-a-base-point#), [issue2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53764754/model-aggregating-in-viewer-coordinate-issue#), [issue3]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66895484/revit-shared-coordinates-to-forge-viewer) topics but none of them has given any good result, am not really sure what am I doing wrong or missing. The screenshot above of F.Viewer was created using the `Autodesk.Viewing.AggregatedView` class. I have also used the [MultipleModelUtil](https://github.com/yiskang/MultipleModelUtil) class by [@Eason Kang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7745569/eason-kang)

Both models are provided through this [gdrive link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1MQUiDwSqasYlPAUvGn4wkf2_h4Ht6PEz?usp=sharing), any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

To use [MultipleModelUtil](https://github.com/yiskang/MultipleModelUtil), you first need to ensure that the two models are in the same coordinate system and sharing with the exact origin. Commonly, RVT and FBX are in different coordinate systems, unit scales, and origins. Therefore, they are not aligned.

The reason why these two models are well-aligned in Navisworks is that Navisworks will do conversions of coordinate systems and origins to the Navisworks internal while converting to NWC files, as I know.